# Loop Access error 424 Loop rs to excel

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
rivate Sub CmdOpenCmtList_Click()

On Error GoTo SubError

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWkb As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWks As Excel.Worksheet

Dim i As Integer  'First Row: CmtAwd
Dim j As Integer  'First Row: CmtJaws
Dim k As Integer  'First Row: CmtSick

Dim l As Integer  'Second Row: CmtCust
Dim m As Integer  'Second Row: CmtJun
Dim n As Integer  'Second Row: CmtMain



Dim SQLCmtAwd As String
'Dim SQLCmtAwdChair As String   'no chairman
Dim SQLCmtJaws As String
Dim SQLCmtJawsChair As String
Dim SQLCmtSick As String
Dim SQLCmtSickChair As String

Dim SQLCmtCust As String
Dim SQLCmtCustChair As String
Dim SQLCmtJun As String
Dim SQLCmtJunChair As String
Dim SQLCmtMain As String
Dim SQLCmtMainChair As String

Dim rsCmtAwd As DAO.Recordset
'Dim rsCmtAwdChair As DAO.Recordset  'no chairmen
Dim rsCmtJaws As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsCmtJawsChair As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsCmtSick As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsCmtSickChair As DAO.Recordset

Dim rsCmtCust As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsCmtCustChair As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsCmtJun As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsCmtJunChair As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsCmtMain As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsCmtMainChair As DAO.Recordset

SQLCmtAwd = "SELECT [FirstName] & "" "" & [LastName] AS FullName, TblMembers.CmtAwd, TblMembers.CmtAwd " & _
    " FROM TblMembers " & _
    " WHERE (((TblMembers.CmtAwd)=True))"
'SQLCmtAwdChair = " SELECT [FirstName] & "" "" & [LastName] AS FullName, TblMembers.CmtAwdChair, [FullName] & "" - Chairman"" AS FullNameChair " & _
'    " FROM TblMembers " & _
'    " WHERE (((TblMembers.CmtAwdChair)=True))"
SQLCmtJaws = "SELECT [FirstName] & "" "" & [LastName] AS FullName, TblMembers.CmtJaws " & _
    " FROM TblMembers " & _
    " WHERE (((TblMembers.CmtJaws)=True))"
SQLCmtJawsChair = " SELECT [FirstName] & "" "" & [LastName] AS FullName, TblMembers.CmtJawsChair, [FullName] & "" - Chairman"" AS FullNameChair " & _
    " FROM TblMembers " & _
    " WHERE (((TblMembers.CmtJawsChair)=True))"
SQLCmtSickChair = " SELECT [FirstName] & "" "" & [LastName] AS FullName, TblMembers.CmtSickChair, [FullName] & "" - Chairman"" AS FullNameChair " & _
    " FROM TblMembers " & _
    " WHERE (((TblMembers.CmtSickChair)=True))"
SQLCmtSick = "SELECT [FirstName] & "" "" & [LastName] AS FullName, TblMembers.CmtSickChair " & _
    " FROM TblMembers " & _
    " WHERE (((TblMembers.CmtSick)=True))"

SQLCmtCustChair = " SELECT [FirstName] & "" "" & [LastName] AS FullName, TblMembers.CmtCustChair, [FullName] & "" - Chairman"" AS FullNameChair " & _
    " FROM TblMembers " & _
    " WHERE (((TblMembers.CmtCustChair)=True))"
SQLCmtCust = "SELECT [FirstName] & "" "" & [LastName] AS FullName, TblMembers.CmtCust " & _
    " FROM TblMembers " & _
    " WHERE (((TblMembers.CmtCust)=True))"

SQLCmtJunChair = " SELECT [FirstName] & "" "" & [LastName] AS FullName, TblMembers.CmtJunChair, [FullName] & "" - Chairman"" AS FullNameChair " & _
    " FROM TblMembers " & _
    " WHERE (((TblMembers.CmtJunChair)=True))"
SQLCmtJun = "SELECT [FirstName] & "" "" & [LastName] AS FullName, TblMembers.CmtJun " & _
    " FROM TblMembers " & _
    " WHERE (((TblMembers.CmtJun)=True))"

SQLCmtMainChair = " SELECT [FirstName] & "" "" & [LastName] AS FullName, TblMembers.CmtMainChair, [FullName] & "" - Chairman"" AS FullNameChair " & _
    " FROM TblMembers " & _
    " WHERE (((TblMembers.CmtMainChair)=True))"
SQLCmtMain = "SELECT [FirstName] & "" "" & [LastName] AS FullName, TblMembers.CmtMainChair " & _
    " FROM TblMembers " & _
    " WHERE (((TblMembers.CmtMain)=True))"

Set rsCmtAwd = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLCmtAwd, dbOpenSnapshot)
'Set rsCmtAwdChair = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLCmtAwdChair, dbOpenSnapshot)
Set rsCmtJaws = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLCmtJaws, dbOpenSnapshot)
Set rsCmtJawsChair = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLCmtJawsChair, dbOpenSnapshot)
Set rsCmtSick = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLCmtSick, dbOpenSnapshot)
Set rsCmtSickChair = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLCmtSickChair, dbOpenSnapshot)

Set rsCmtCust = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLCmtCust, dbOpenSnapshot)
Set rsCmtCustChair = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLCmtCustChair, dbOpenSnapshot)
Set rsCmtJun = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLCmtJun, dbOpenSnapshot)
Set rsCmtJunChair = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLCmtJunChair, dbOpenSnapshot)
Set rsCmtMain = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLCmtMain, dbOpenSnapshot)
Set rsCmtMainChair = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLCmtMainChair, dbOpenSnapshot)

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
Set xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(CurrentProject.Path & "\Master\CommitteeList.xlsx")
Set xlWks = xlWkb.Sheets("Sheet1")
xlApp.Visible = True


i = 10 'First Row: CmtAwd
j = 10  'First Row: CmtJaws
k = 10 'First Row: CmtSick


With xlWks
    Do While Not rsCmtAwdChair.EOF
        .Range("E9").Value = (rsCmtAwdChair!FullNameChair)
        rsCmtAwdChair.MoveNext
    Loop
End With
With xlWks
    Do While Not rsCmtAwd.EOF
        .Range("E" & i - 1).Value = Nz(rsCmtAwd!FullName, "")
        i = i + 1
    rsCmtAwd.MoveNext
    Loop
End With
With xlWks
    Do While Not rsCmtJawsChair.EOF
        .Range("Y9").Value = (rsCmtJawsChair!FullNameChair)
        rsCmtJawsChair.MoveNext
    Loop
End With
With xlWks
    Do While Not rsCmtJaws.EOF
        .Range("Y" & j).Value = Nz(rsCmtJaws!FullName, "")
        j = j + 1
    rsCmtJaws.MoveNext
    Loop
End With
With xlWks
    Do While Not rsCmtSickChair.EOF
        .Range("AS9").Value = (rsCmtSickChair!FullNameChair)
        rsCmtSickChair.MoveNext
    Loop
End With

With xlWks
    Do While Not rsCmtSick.EOF
        .Range("AS" & k).Value = Nz(rsCmtSick!FullName, "")
        k = k + 1
    rsCmtSick.MoveNext
    Loop
End With




With xlWks
    Do While Not rsCmtCustChair.EOF
        .Range("E16").Value = (rsCmtCustChair!FullNameChair)
        rsCmtCustChair.MoveNext
    Loop
End With
With xlWks
    Do While Not rsCmtCust.EOF
        .Range("AS" & i).Value = Nz(rsCmtCust!FullName, "")
        i = i + 17
    rsCmtSick.MoveNext
    Loop
End With



With xlWks
    Do While Not rsCmtJunChair.EOF
        .Range("Y16").Value = (rsCmtJunChair!FullNameChair)
        rsCmtJunChair.MoveNext
    Loop
End With

With xlWks
    Do While Not rsCmtJun.EOF
        .Range("Y" & m).Value = Nz(rsCmtJun!FullName, "")
        m = m + 1
    rsCmtSick.MoveNext
    Loop
End With


With xlWks
    Do While Not rsCmtMainChair.EOF
        .Range("AS16").Value = (rsCmtMainChair!FullNameChair)
        rsCmtMainChair.MoveNext
    Loop
End With
With xlWks
    Do While Not rsCmtMain.EOF
        .Range("Y" & n).Value = Nz(rsCmtMain!FullName, "")
        n = n + 1
    rsCmtMain.MoveNext
    Loop
End With





SubExit:

On Error Resume Next

rsCmtAwd.Close
'rsCmtAwdChair.Close
rsCmtJaws.Close
rsCmtJawsChair.Close
rsCmtSick.Close
rsCmtSickChair.Close

rsCmtCust.Close
rsCmtCustChair.Close
rsCmtJun.Close
rsCmtJunChair.Close
rsCmtMain.Close
rsCmtMainChair.Close

Set rsCmtAwd = Nothing
'Set rsCmtAwdChair = Nothing
Set rsCmtJaws = Nothing
Set rsCmtJawsChair = Nothing
Set rsCmtSick = Nothing
Set rsCmtSickChair = Nothing

Set rsCustAwd = Nothing
Set rsCmtCustChair = Nothing
Set rsCmtJun = Nothing
Set rsCmtJunChair = Nothing
Set rsCmtMain = Nothing
Set rsCmtSickMain = Nothing


Exit Sub

SubError:

MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & "=" & Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "An error occured"
 GoTo SubExit


End Sub
```

Is there a better way to do this.  I solved my previous problem, but now I get an error of 424 object required.  Before the object error I was getting no record error, I checked the queries all return records.

Is there a better way to loop thru rs and get the output to the excel file, I have about 18 committes that need to have a chairman and 1-5 members.  Cells on excel ie... Y16 for Chairman and then in y17 the list of members.

Comment: Comment out your `On Error` line: where does the error occur?

Comment: ^^ and after that, please read [mcve] and reduce your code to the relevant part(s).

Answer (score 0):

1-
Instead of looping, you can use 'CopyfromRecordSet'. You just need to select the starting cell on each sheet of your Excel file, and the system do the rest.
I give you the Microsoft link:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223845(v=office.11).aspx

2-
On the 424 Object required problem, did you try to debug the code to find out which line the error occurs?

Hope this can help!

Comment: Someplace along the way I was told not to use that method and to use the with .Range method.  I also tried the .Cells method and was directed back to the .Range vs.   For some reason I was always directed away from copyfromrecordset.